# Android mapView ItemizedOverlay setFocus does not work properly

Tags: android, google-maps, setfocus, itemizedoverlay

Calling `setFocus(null)` on the `ItemizedOverlay` does not 'unfocus' current marker. According to the documentation:

> ... If the Item is not found, this is a no-op. You can also pass null to remove focus.

Here's my code:

*MapItemizedOverlay*

```
public class MapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MapItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(defaultMarker);
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        items.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

}
```

Creating map overlay and one marker:

```
StateListDrawable youIcon = (StateListDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_icon);
int width = youIcon.getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = youIcon.getIntrinsicHeight();
youIcon.setBounds(-13, 0-height, -13+width, 0);
GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint(40800816,-74122009);

MapItemizedOverlay overlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(youIcon);
OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(location, "title", "snippet");
overlay.addOverlay(item);
mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
```

The `R.drawable.marker_icon` is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/marker_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/marker_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/marker_normal" />
</selector>
```

Now, to test the setFocus() behavior I put the button on the activity window, with the following onClick listener:

```
Button focusBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.focusbtn);
focusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for(Overlay ov : mapView.getOverlays())
        {
            if(ov.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MapItemizedOverlay") == true)
            {
                MapItemizedOverlay miv = (MapItemizedOverlay)ov;
                if(miv.getFocus() == null)
                    miv.setFocus(miv.getItem(0));
                else
                    miv.setFocus(null);
                break;
            }
        }
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

The expected behavior is: clicking on the button toggles marker selection.

It works only once - clicking it for the first time selects the marker, clicking it again does not de-select the marker. The most weird thing about it is that after calling setFocus(null), getFocus() also returns null - like the overlay has no focused item (I debugged it). But even after calling mapView.invalidate() the marker is still drawn in 'selected'(focused) state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rpond said in a comment to my question, it looks like an open bug in the API.

In the meantime I solved it myself. Below is the workaround code. You need to extend the `OverlayItem` class and check what `overlay.getFocus()` is returning.

```
public class MapOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

    MapItemizedOverlay overlay = null;

    public MapOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, MapItemizedOverlay ov)
    {
        super(point, null, null);
        this.overlay = ov;
    }

    public MapOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet) {
        super(point, title, snippet);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getMarker(int stateBitset) {
        Drawable icon = overlay.getDefaultMarker();

        if(stateBitset == 0)
            return icon;

        OverlayItem focusedItem = overlay.getFocus();

        if(focusedItem == null) {
            OverlayItem.setState(icon, 0);
            return icon;
        }

        if(focusedItem.equals(this) == true)
            OverlayItem.setState(icon, stateBitset);
        else
            OverlayItem.setState(icon, 0);

        return icon;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be a bug?

[MapView setFocus does not work if the overlay item was the last focused item](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6752)

Comment: Perhaps. I have an idea for workaround, but I have to test it first.

Comment: It seems that when the OverlayItem gains the focus for the 1st time, the MapView look for the StateListDrawable "state_focused". If you reselect it again, the MapView look for "state_selected" !

Comment: this api stinks, it is terribly designed and has lots of bugs!